# Quickfix\N Logout before Logon

Tags: authentication, logout, quickfixn

I have a quickfix service where some clients connect in the morning. Everything works fine except for a reason: The first conenction message (35=A) in the morning gets rejected:

8=FIX.4.49=74 **35=5 34=1** 49=xxxFIXMDFServer 52=20160520 12:40:02.882 56=CLIENTyyy 10=106

Then, on the next attempt to logon, everything works fine:

8=FIX.4.4 9=88 **35=A 34=2** 49=CLIENTyyy 52=20160520-12:40:02 56=xxxFIXMDFServer 98=0 108=30 141=N 10=231

8=FIX.4.4 9=86 **35=A 34=1** 49=xxxFIXMDFServer 52=20160520-12:40:03.163 56=CLIENTyyy 98=0 108=30 10=139

Besides:

- All sequence numbers are reset to one during the night
- Even when it is not seen in the logs, a 35=A, 34=1 message is sent before the disconnection message (35=5)
- After logon, everything works fine even if the client disconnects during the evening.

Any ideas? Maybe a bug in the quickfix library?

Thanks!